# How to remove or hide some sections in a HTML color picker

Tags: html, css, color-picker

I want to hide or remove the two green sections in the HTML color picker.
I searched a lot but I did not find any useful posts.

[image: HTML color pciker]

Is it possible to do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a built in colour picker, or a library? If it's built-in, I doubt you can change it, if it's a library, we'll need to know which one to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

What your are trying to do will not work. You will need to use a JavaScript Framework or Library for that. The default input['color'] is native and you cant change the style of the picker.

Try something like [TinyColorPicker](https://baijs.com/tinycolorpicker/)